# Implement multiple REST servers on same Loopback 4 app

Tags: express, loopback4

Can we create multiple `REST` servers in single `loopback` app?

My requirement is running two REST servers (say 8080 and 8081 on `localhost`) but to have same app. My implementation will be, receiving some data from 8080, process them and return some results on 8081.

The absolute reason for above requirement is the lack of `Socket.io` integration for `loopback 4`. Any solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lack of Socket.io integration for LoopBack 4

While LoopBack 4 does not provide first-class Socket.io integration yet, there is [an example](https://github.com/raymondfeng/loopback4-example-websocket) provided by a core maintainer of the project.

> Can we create multiple REST servers in single loopback app?

Yes. Additional servers can be added with `app.server()` or bulk-added with `app.servers()`.

Further reading:

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Application.html#servers